# Права доступа к файлам в Винде

Tags: php, администрирование

Пусть имеются права доступа к некоторым файлам с кодами 0666 и 0777.
В windows функция fileperms() выдает соответственно 33206 и 16895. Переведя эти данные в восьмеричную систему я получил 0100666 и 0040777, которые по своему значению естественно не равны 0666 и 0777. Почему так происходит? Не вызывает ли это определенную путаницу, и вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Та вроде никакой путаницы. Посмотрите примеры вот [здесь](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php)

Можно, например, вызывать функцию как-то так:

```
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('file/path')), -4); //выведет 0666 для файла с правами 0666
```

А вообще PHP спроектирован не совсем удачно. Надеюсь я никого не обижу этим. Так что в этом языке довольно много вещей, так сказать, не интуитивно понятных.

Comment: А вот скрипт :
        echo fileperms('text.txt');
 chmod('text.txt',0600);
 echo fileperms('text.txt');
Однако после работы скрипта права остались неизменными - 33206.

Comment: @Deus, может быть у Вас нет прав на смену прав? Или нет этих прав у сервера?

Comment: Как разобраться? У меня localhost. И у меня нет прав на личном сервере для смены прав на личные файлы? ))

Answer (score 1):

Дело в специфике формата возвращаемого значения [fileperms](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php)

```
echo substr(decoct( fileperms('index.html') ), 2);
```